# Zlib Deflate in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, zlib

So I'm trying to recreate and implement a section of code from a JavaScript file. I need to be able to use "Zlib.Deflate.compress" or something equivalent that will get me the exact same results.

I downloaded Zlib which included the .dll, 2 header files and a .lib file. but i cant figure out how to implement this into my application. I've tried to add it as a resource but i keep getting an error "A reference could not be added. Please make sure this file is accessible, and its a valid assembly or COM Component"

I tried using the method on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx to create a .dll file out of the header and .lib files, but that gave me a build error as well.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: If i use the native System.Compression, will it compress in the exact same manor and give me the same result though? That's what I'm worried about.

Comment: MS says they meet the standard, if you don't believe them then write a test app to verify. My bet is that they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the native .NET [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class it should do exactly what you're looking for and doesn't require any third party libraries. Just the framework itself.